# How to save the row order position in ranked model gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using `ranked model gem` and following along with 
[sortable tables tutorial](http://benw.me/posts/sortable-bootstrap-tables/)

I have tasks model.

**task.rb**

```
include RankedModel
ranks :row_order
```

**routes**

```
 resources :tasks do
 post :update_row_order, on: :collection
```

**tasks_controller.rb**

```
  def update_row_order
   @task = Task.find(params[:task][:task_id])
   @task.row_order_position = params[:task][:row_order_position]
   @task.save
   render nothing: true 
  end
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax(
      type: 'POST'
      url: '/tasks/update_row_order'
      dataType: 'json'
      data: { task: {task_id: item_id, row_order_position: position } }
```

After Drag the task

**Trace**

`Parameters: {"task"=>{"task_id"=>"141", "row_order_position"=>"0"}}`

In table i have column row_order in that save the some random value like `row_order` = `-8343750`. 
Is it possible to save the `row_order_position` in db. Like 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is how ranked model works. If you are wanting numbers like 1,2,3 you should be using [acts_as_lists](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list). Ranked model is more efficient though.

This is how it works

> Ranked-model only performs an update operation on the item in
>   question. It achieves this by creating a rank number that is midway
>   between the two neighbors, these numbers are spread out across a very
>   wide range; -8388607 to 8388607 (the extents of a signed MEDIUMINT in
>   MySQL.
>
> What happens if, after a few thousand re-sorts on a list there is
>   actually an overlap with rank-numbers, or they end up out of range?
>   Well, in that rare scenario the whole table will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

(The following is not an exact answer to the question above but assumes that you want to save the task to be able to retrieve it later on. It can also be used to position a task relative to another task.)

It is not recommendable to save a row_order_position in the DB by using RankedModel. The main advantage of ranked model's approach is that you don't need to save all row_order_positions that come after the one you've edited.

If you want to save it to the DB to be able to easily ascertain the row_order_position of a specific task you can do the following:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base

include RankedModel
ranks :row_order

def calculated_row_order_position
  self.siblings.where('row_order < ?', self.row_order).count + 1
end
```

This is based on a post found [here](https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model/issues/33) which is based on [this post](https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model/issues/10). I added the "+ 1" to get the row position starting your count of tasks at 1. The solution above assumes that you use ancestry to organise tasks in a tree structure ancestry uses .sibling to get all siblings.

By adding the method calculated_row_order_position it's not necessary to save the row_order_position to be able to easily get a task's position.

If i'm not mistaken you can now decide what is easier on your DB: 
1. Saving the changed position of all tasks that come after the task which position you change when saving (acts-as-list is your best option).
or 
2. querying the row_order of sibling tasks when you need to ascertain the row_order_position of a specific task (pick ranked model gem).

Please let me know if I'm missing anything or if the above comparison between acts-as-list and ranked model is not correct.